# How to get '\x01' to 1

Tags: python

I am getting this:

```
_format_ = "7c7sc"
print struct.unpack(self._format_, data)
```

gives

```
('\x7f', 'E', 'L', 'F', '\x01', '\x01', '\x01', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', '\x00')
```

I want to take `'\x01'` and get 1 from it, i.e., convert to ``int. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ord("\x01")` will return 1.

Comment: How would I handle a  2-byte integer, like ```b'\x00\x80'```?

Comment: I came up with ```int("0x" + ''.join([hex(x)[2:] for x in byte_string]), base=16)``` but that can't be the best way...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are thinking of the `ord` function?

```
>>> ord("\x01")
1
>>> ord("\x02")
2
>>> ord("\x7f")
127
```